# Button Title changing unexpectedly in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` created with the following code:

```
applyButton= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 636, 150, 50)];
[applyButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
[applyButton setTitle:@"MyTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 applyButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
[[applyButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[applyButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];

applyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[applyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveSettingsToNSUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:applyButton];
```

The button appears with "MyTitle" in light gray colour initially.
But when i presses it the title colour turns white and the "saveSettingsToNSUser" function is called.There is NOTHING inside the function "saveSettingsToNSUser" which affects the button. I don't understand what is happening. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setTitleColor:forState:` to set title label color.

```
[applyButton setTitleColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
applyButton= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 636, 150, 50)];
//set title
[applyButton setTitle:@"MyTitle" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[applyButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
[applyButton setTitle:@"MyTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 applyButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
[[applyButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[applyButton layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];

applyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[applyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveSettingsToNSUser:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:applyButton];
```